# Override attributes in ABAP classes?

Tags: oop, inheritance, attributes, abap

let's say that I created a class `ZCL_WORKORDER_GENERIC` with one attribute which is a table of `ZCL_OPERATIONS_GENERIC` objects.

Now I would like to create a new class `ZCL_WORKORDER_SPECIFIC1` inheriting from the first, but the list of operations should also be overridden with a class `ZCL_OPERATIONS_SPECIFIC1`.

What would be the best way to achieve this in ABAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you **cannot** override attributes, it is prohibited by ABAP OO model.

However, you can do the following trick: declare attribute of your superclass as of type `DATA` (aka [data object](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abendata_object_glosry.htm)) and then assign any type you want to it in the sub-class which extends your superclass.

Provided you have two type of operations, which uniquely identify themselves: **zcl_operations_generic**:

```
CLASS zcl_operations_generic DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA l_wheel TYPE char5 VALUE 'wheel'.
  METHODS: identify_me.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_operations_generic IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD identify_me.
    WRITE: `I am `, condense( cl_abap_classdescr=>get_class_name( me ) ), `and I have a`, l_wheel.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

and more specific **zcl_operations_specific1**

```
CLASS zcl_operations_specific1 DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA l_wheel TYPE char10 VALUE 'truckwheel'.
  METHODS: who_am_i.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_operations_specific1 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD who_am_i.
    WRITE: `I am `, condense( cl_abap_classdescr=>get_class_name( me ) ), `and I have a`, l_wheel.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Then when creating generic work order **zcl_workorder_generic** you specify operation `mr_data` as generic type and do necessary type initializations in constructor and method:

```
CLASS zcl_workorder_generic DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA mr_data TYPE REF TO data.
    METHODS initialize EXPORTING out_order TYPE ANY.
    METHODS constructor.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_workorder_generic IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD initialize.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lr_data> TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_generic.
    ASSIGN mr_data->* TO <lr_data>.
    CREATE OBJECT <lr_data>.
    out_order = <lr_data>.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD constructor.
    CREATE DATA mr_data TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_generic.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

and in specific work order **zcl_workorder_specific1** you should redefine constructor/initialization methods for new type:

```
CLASS zcl_workorder_specific1 DEFINITION INHERITING FROM zcl_workorder_generic.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS initialize REDEFINITION.
    METHODS constructor.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_workorder_specific1 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD initialize.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lr_data> TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_specific1.
    ASSIGN mr_data->* TO <lr_data>.
    CREATE OBJECT <lr_data>.
    out_order = <lr_data>.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD constructor.
    super->constructor( ).
    CREATE DATA mr_data TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_specific1.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Then you can instantiate your orders like this, and then check if the attributes are properly instantiated by calling corresponding attribute methods:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.

  DATA: generic TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_generic.
  DATA(lr_work_order) = NEW zcl_workorder_generic( ).
  lr_work_order->initialize( IMPORTING out_order = generic ).
  generic->identify_me( ).

  WRITE: /.

  DATA: specific TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_specific1.
  lr_work_order = NEW zcl_workorder_specific1( ).
  lr_work_order->initialize( IMPORTING out_order = specific ).
  specific->who_am_i( ).
```

But it is just a tricky workaround and I agree with Florian overriding attributes is a bad approach that shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is technically the correct answer to my original question. It doesn't solve my actual problem because I didn't ask the proper question but it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have

```
CLASS zcl_workorder_generic DEFINITION.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    DATA operations TYPE REF TO zcl_operations_generic.
ENDCLASS.
```

Then you can easily derive

```
CLASS zcl_workorder_specific1 DEFINITION INHERITING FROM zcl_workorder_generic.
ENDCLASS
```

and that sub-class will naturally have access to `operations`, typed as `zcl_operations_generic`.

Your specific operations can then be

```
CLASS zcl_operations_specific1 DEFINITION INHERITING FROM zcl_operations_generic.
ENDCLASS.
```

In object-oriented design, `zcl_operations_specific1` must be a true sub-class of `zcl_operations_generic`. If you feel the need to add/change methods to `~specific1` which are not part of `~generic`, your object-oriented design is faulty because it violates the [Liskov substituion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). "Faulty" meaning you can still make it work, somehow, with a lot of CASTs, but you will work against your design instead of letting yourself being carried by it.

In any way, you should add interfaces. Inheritance is a means to share code between implementations. Interfaces declare contracts between classes, and give you more independence, for example when writing unit tests.

Comment: But I don't want that my class ZCL_WORKORDER_SPECIFIC1 has the generic operations. I would like them to be the specific ones. Is this a faulty design? For instance if I had a generic VEHICLE class with 4 WHEELS, when I create a VEHICLE_TRUCK class, I would like it to have 4 TRUCK_WHEELS because I already know that a truck has this specific type of wheels.

Comment: Let's say `vehicle` has a list of `wheel`s as `public` property. `truck` inherits from `vehicle`, and with that also has that property. Now imagine `truck` would change ("override") the property's type to `truck_wheel`. If I give you an instance of `truck`, you'd rightfully expect to get `truck_wheel`s. But what would you expect if I give you an instance of `vehicle`? Would it be `wheel`s or `truck_wheel`s? You'd have to differentiate the instance's type first to be able to tell what you get.

Comment: OK, thank you. I understand the problem when I got an instance of a vehicle, but then I still don't know how to design the things from my original question. My specific work order must have specific operations because they have additional methods an attributes. After trying to learn a bit, maybe what I need is to use a decorator then? If so, how could I "decorate" the list of operations to add the additional methods and attributes?

Comment: You can add as many new properties and methods as you’d like. The thing you cannot do is changing the ones you inherited. The thing you can but shouldn’t do is calling the added members - it’s technically possible but against good class design.

Comment: Thanks. With your answers I think finally understood what is my actual problem and that I formulated the question in a wrong way. The issue is that my project uses Operations for business concepts that don't seem to have any relationship with what SAP considers an operation, making the generic operation class an object to interact with the SAP BAPIs. I didn't want that my specific work order had a list of operations, but for instance a list of what they call "disciplines". I can achieve this with interfaces, but internally the class still has the "operations" attribute and it feels wrong.

Comment: Good answer Florian. RaTio should be using interfaces for this type of problem. What makes this matter worse, ABAP isnt a full OO language as it DOESNT support polymorphism.